# Cloud9 IDE - Getting Workspace URL and user email in terminal

Tags: cloud9-ide, cloud9

I'm writing a bash script, and I need to get from within the terminal current workspace URL and the cloud9 user email.

I've tried:

- Extracting the data from hostname variable, but it's not the workspace domain.
- Extracting it from the .c9 project folders, but the domain and user email doesn't seem to appear there

Any ideas how could I get these details from within the c9 terminal?

Comment: What's the issue you're having with extracting it from the hostname? The hostname should be username-workspacename-workspaceid. Just scrap the id then use workspacename-username.c9users.io for the preview URL. For the workspace URL you'll want https://ide.c9.io/username/workspacename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on hosted workspaces you can use `$C9_*` environment variables, try

```
echo $C9_EMAIL $C9_FULLNAME $C9_HOSTNAME $C9_PROJECT
```